CSS layer with class definition overrides style with pseudo-class in parent layer
The CSS layers the interesting thing, because it allows to circumvent cascading of CSS.
But I don't understand why do inherited layer overlap the .item:hover selector? Did I write something wrong somewhere?


@layer base, special;

@layer base {
  .item {
    color: green;
    border: 5px solid green;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .item:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}

@layer special {
  .item {
    color: rebeccapurple;
  }
}
<div class="item">Hello world!</div>



I expect the transition from rebeccapurple to red, but didn't get it.

well the later layer's css will always overwrite the former layer's css disregarding the higher class specificity from :hover.

@SyndRain I know that, but notice that the later layer doesn't have :hover pseudo-class. What's wrong?

You might be confusing between pseudo classes and pseudo elements. For example, #my-id::after and #my-id are targeting two different elements, but #my-id:hover and #my-id are targeting the same element.

@SyndRain nope, I understand difference between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. When I declare a new rule in a new (later) layer for a concrete element, the browser "forget" about pseudo-classes for the element in parent layer? Am I right? Where can I read about that detailed?

Let me just post an answer I guess, it's easier to explain.

In CSS, when both selectors are selecting the same element and applies the same property, browser chooses which property to apply based on Cascading order, where you can see Specificity is less important than Layers as mentioned in the link:

The cascade lies at the core of CSS, as emphasized by the name: Cascading Style Sheets. When a selector matches an element, the property value from the origin with the highest precedence gets applied, even if the selector from a lower precedence origin or layer has greater specificity.

I did not see this in the list in MDN, but in the spec Layer's position in Cascading Order is mentioned as such:

Origin and Importance
Context
Element-Attached Styles
Layers
Specificity
Order of Appearance

To sum up, Cascading layers is considered less important than origin but more important than specificity. Hence, no matter how you select the element in the base layer, by pseudo classes (such as :hover), or Id, or whatever, it will always be overwrite by later layers in the same stylesheet.

With the above knowledge, looking at your example, if all layers are removed, the hovering transition happens because it was originally purple from .item with specificity (0,1,0). When you hover it, it is selected by .item:hover which has specificity (0,2,0), so the red color overwrites the purple color.
This doesn't happen when they are grouped into layers such as in your case, because even when its hovered, the :hover selector is still in a lower layer, so it doesn't overwrite .item in the higher layer even if it has higher specificity.
If you look into the devs tool, you can see all 3 declarations, while the one in layer special is applied. Hence, I'm not sure if using the term "forgot" is correct since its simply one declaration overwritten by another. You won't say the browser forgots a declaration if its overwritten by another declaration with !important.
In terms of Cascading order, selecting an element with :hover has nothing different with selecting an element with another class like .item .item2 and certainly is not an exception of the rule mentioned above.

This is still unclear to me. Just take my code example and remove all layers, rest only css rules and you will see transition that I waited. I don't understand layers logic that block parent :hover rule.

I've updated the answer to explain why :hover will be applied if removing layers, hope this makes it clear.

You claim that :hover is in the lower layer and therefore it does not overwrite .item in the upper layer - well, that's right, I do not define :hover in the upper layer, because I want to keep the old :hover styles.
P.S. I understand how the cascade works and that the styles of the lower layers can be overwritten by the styles of the upper layers (in the order of their declaration, the later the higher the priority).

Ah I see, I thought you were confused by why the :hover is overwritten. I might not be understanding your question then. So what is the thing that is confusing you?

I appreciate your efforts, but I personally don't find the answer in your post. Looks like I'll have to read the spec. Thanks for the effort, you definitely deserve a +1.

np. If you want to you can discribe what's the question you are finding answer for and I'll be happy to anwer or research. English is not my native language so I often misunderstand things.

@SynRain my question was: "why am i not inheriting :hover from the parent layer and as a result i don't get the transition from rebeccapurple to red?" That was my question.

I don’t understand what you mean by ‘parent layer’. The layer you call base is in no way a parent. And in fact, because of the order in which you have declared them, it has less precedence than special. Specificity between layers has no relevance. If you’ve set a CSS property for an element in a higher layer that will be what is used, regardless of specificity.

@AHaworth probably I make a misspeling in relation to CSS layers.
What I mean under parenting: @layer base /*(parent)*/, special. Sure it doesn't look like that one layer is parent for another, my bad.
Yes I overridden the .item class but I didn't override .item:hover. So the styles for .item changed but not for .item:hover. So I don't understand if I didn't override .item:hover then why the hover effect doesn't work from the previous layer?

Because layers work on the actual element, not on classes (or ids).
